# retrieve specific columns from crm dynamics built in entity using Talend Open Studio

Tags: dynamics-crm, talend, dynamics-crm-online

I have a requirement to integrate CRM dynamics 365 with MySQL db. The available tool is Talend Open Studio. So I have a few queries

-I need to retrieve a few columns from accounts, leads,opportunities, but I could not find a way to restrict the columns returns. Is there any way we can do it using **tMicrosoftCrmInput**? I am getting all the columns now.

- How to do an incremental/delta data sync using Talend Open studio? I need to get the newly created and updated items
- I tried to use tRestClient as well. but basic authentication getting failed with 401 error. How the headers and auth setting should be done?

Also,under basic settings when we use Authentication Type as : Online;ApI Version as:v2016(odata); Registered application type as:Web app with delegated permissions, why we need to give username,password along applicationid and secret?

Answer (score 0):

It could be quite tough to get data from CRM Dynamics with talend.
To connect to Microsoft CRM Dynamics, i used tRESTClient , i didn't manage to get all i wanted with tMicrosoftCRMinput component.
Firsty you have to authenticate. My advice : try first to do it with a software like Postman. If you succeed with postman, you will be able to do it with talend (and if you don't, then problem is not talend).
You have to use a tRESTClient to connect to the auth service (https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/token)
Here is an exampleof my tRESTClient config. You'll need clientid and secret, i think user/password is not mandatory if you have id and secret. "resource" is the url to your dynamics crm. When connection is OK, retrieve token with a json extraction.
[image]